# Oracle APEX 5 - Validation against the total set of an interactive grid

Tags: oracle-apex-5

This is a simplified version of my task, but captures the problem nicely.

I have a table:

```
Id   Number 
-
Desc Varchar2(20) 
-
Flag Varchar2(1) --Only accepts values Y or N
-
```

and I have an interactive grid based on that table.

The user will normally be faced with several rows that they can amend, add to or delete.

So the user can play around with the IG, but when they hit Save, I need a validation message to appear if Flag=Y occurs more than one time. Of course any value of Flag=Y may not be newly entered, it may have been retrieved from the database and not amended. However other values of Flag=Y could appear through insertions and amendments.

This functionality was originally on an Oracle Form where I could loop through the multi-row block before commit and count the occurrences of Flag=Y. It appears I cannot do this with the IG since validations only examines updated/created records no matter what the Execution Scope.

So anyone any ideas how this functionality can be achieved. I've ran out of them.